# Updating multiple entities with DDD

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, domain-driven-design, hexagonal-architecture

I am working on an application with Spring Boot and Java and JPA. I am going with DDD and it has multiple modules, the application, the domain, and the infrastructure layer. The domain is in plain Java.

I have a domain entity `Account`. One user can have multiple accounts. Accounts have a type and `State` but only one account can be 'Active' the rest needs to be 'Inactive'. If I want to change the state of one of the accounts of a user then I have to change two accounts. The 'Active' one to 'Inactive' and the 'Inactive' one to 'Active'. This brings up transactional management. I don't know what would be the proper way to handle this in the domain layer.

```
enum State {
  ACTIVE, INACTIVE
}
```

```
class Account {
  private String userId;
  private State state;
  private String type;
}
```

```
class AccountService {

  Account activate(Account accountToActivate) {
    // various checks

    // 1. inactivate active -> save in JPA repo
    // 2. activate accountToActivate -> save in JPA repo
    // 1 + 2 should be in transaction

    // return activatedAccount
  }
}
```

- I thought I should write some rollback behavior if the second task fails. But on the other hand, it would bring some serious complexity.
- Using Springs `@Transactional` looks like a good thing at first but I believe it would bring in other problems in the long run.

Should I redesign my aggregate? I cannot think of a different solution. How would you solve this? What are your experiences?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a set of things that must always be in agreement, then that set of things must be part of the same "aggregate".  Evans's definition of aggregate:

> An AGGREGATE is a cluster of associated objects that we treat as a unit for the purpose of data changes

> Any rule that spans multiple AGGREGATES will not be expected to be up to date at all times.

That doesn't *necessarily* mean that all of your account entities need to be part of the same aggregate.  It could be that your account aggregates are over there, and your User aggregate over here holds an identifier for the active account.  Or it could be that the user's history of active accounts is an aggregate all by itself, separate from the user.

Lots of possible answers, depending on what other parts of the system care about "active" accounts, [what is the business impact of having a failure](https://web.archive.org/web/20101221183328/http://codebetter.com/gregyoung/2010/08/12/eventual-consistency-and-set-validation/), and so on.

Comment: Actually, we have written our very first methods here. I don't have any other entity (now), but its structure is well defined and I cannot modify it. The only part I can control is how I use it in our domain layer. It is a hard constraint that a user can have only one active account. I cannot tell if I will have to use the list of accounts in some other context in the future. I really like the idea that I should use accounts as a list. Maybe it is a beginner question but do I have to extract the aggregate from the method into a class? Or only when I need it multiple times?

Answer (score 0):

Your account class looks like an ORM DPO, not a DDD entity. Especially the state enum is not a good object modeling of your business logic. This is a better example of DDD model for your business contraints:

```cs
public class Account
{
  public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
public class User
{
  public string Identifier { get; }
  public List<Account> Accounts { get; }
  public Account ActiveAccount { get; private set; }
  public void SetActive(Account account)
  {
    // redacted
  }
}
```

How this model is persisted and translated into a relational model (or a JSON document stored in a NoSQL database, an XML file accessed through FTPS, or any other exotic persistence mechanism), is out of the scope of DDD and is the responsibility of the infrastructure layer.